# Is it possible to upgrade a SQL Server 2000 database to 2005 without knowing it?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to upgrade a SQL Server 2000 database to SQL Server 2005 in-place without knowing you did it? In other words, can this upgrade happen accidentally?

We had an incident today. Our application just stopped working. We requested the consultant modify a stored procedure and within a few hours, the phone started ringing... no one could access our app and those that were able to, could not access SSRS.

Fast forward a few hours and many emails between all the players, the consultant concluded the database was upgraded to 2005.

Comment: Never trust a programmer in a suit.

Comment: That is a weird conclusion to come to. Can you give more details on what "stopped working" means? What evidence led anyone to believe that SQL Server 2005 magically broke the app, or that it was SQL Server 2000 before it broke?

Comment: The db should be 2000 and the consultant said it had been upgraded to 2005, thus breaking SSRS and the app. I'm not buying that explanation. I was just in the db an hour ago and, after the db restore by the consultant, the db compatibility level is still 2005.

Comment: What compat level does the last known good database backup restore to?

Comment: @ p.campbell - When I checked the restored database, the compat level was SQL Server 2005 (90) Everything is working fine this morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're speaking of the SQL Server instance, then *no*. That takes a lot of effort, multiple steps, with Administrative credentials on the Windows machine.

If you're speaking of the database's compatibility level, then yes. All it takes is a few clicks in SSMS (Properties-Options-Compatibility level), or a one-liner of TSQL. It'd require db_owner credentials.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90;
```

or

```
sp_dbcmptlevel MyDatabase, 90
```

There's nothing 'automatic'. Only a script or mis-step in SSMS could 'silently' make this change.

Comment: but even the compatibility level isn't *automatic*. Although it appears pretty simple, someone still needs to change it.